# Rails fullname method, wrap in spans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model

I have a simple method on a `Person` model like so:

```
def fullname
    [title, forenames, surname].join(" ")
end
```

Sometimes, the output I get from this is perfect, othertimes I need each part wrapped in a span with a class.  I could do this in the method but it sort of feels wrong to be putting spans in the model.

Can anyone offer a nicer solution?  How would you get this method to offer both of the following output options:

1. Title Forenames Surname
2. <span class"title">Title <span class"forenames">Forenames <span class"surname">Surname

Thanks

Comment: You could have another implementation that emits spans. Put it in a view helper, for example. Or a view model / decorator, if you use those in the project.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The solution below works but feels wrong due to the inclusion of spans.  Any examples of how this could be done with a view helper or a decorator (never looked into those before).   I posted because I couldn;t figure out how to get it to work but separating the concerns etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def fullname(spanned = false)
  {
      'title': title,
      'forenames': forenames,
      'surname': surname
  }.map { |k,v| spanned ? "<span class='#{k}'>#{v}</span>" : v }.join(' ')
end


puts(fullname(true))
# result: <span class='title'>title</span> <span class='forenames'>forenames</span> <span class='surname'>surname</span>

puts(fullname)
# result: title forenames surname
```

Comment: "but it sort of feels wrong to be putting spans in the model" - I concur that a model should not, indeed, contain presentation logic.

Comment: This works perfectly but as stated in my OP, the putting of spans in the model feels incorrect.  Any suggestions to put the spans somewhere else?

Comment: @rctneil I think you're trying to show the spans on some view. so, why not using the helper file to render the span based fullname?